# Create a symbolic link to a named pipe

Tags: windows, command-line, symbolic-link, named-pipe

Let's say some application exposes a named pipe with the name "Pipe1". If I want to express the named pipe as a file path that can be used for writing or reading, the path `\\.\pipe\Pipe1` or `\\?\pipe\Pipe1` is valid and points to the named pipe.

Now for easier validation of the path (some applications may not like the `\\.\`), I thought maybe a symlink could be used to point to the named pipe device. I tried creating the link via `mklink link \\.\pipe\Pipe1`, `mklink link \\?\pipe\Pipe1`, and also `mklink link \\?\GlobalRoot\Device\NamedPipe\Pipe1`, but all of these fail when trying to open the link, with the following error:

> The data present in the reparse point buffer is invalid

Does it make sense what I am trying to do? Can a symlink point to any path and not just into the file system? Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Strangely, I kinda remember that I was trying to solve this problem before, and the symlink worked this way, more or less. Also a symbolic link is the only usable type, creating a hard link fails (because pipe is not on an NTFS partition) and a directory link or a junction cannot be used for i/o.

Comment: What if you try it with the [`/H` – _Hard link_ or the `/J` – _Directory Junction_ option](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx)?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Hard link cannot be used, it can point only to a real file on the same partition, and a directory cannot be used for writing or reading.